# How to display each 3 item in a rows and continues loop to end?

Tags: php, loops

I have a list item `Album` contains 30 albums.

I tried to display all them in the browser with 1 rows contain 3 items.

With code like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        foreach($listAlbum as $item) {
            <div class="col-md-4">$item['imgUrl']</div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I want for each continues to loop all `.col-md-4`.

If I again using `foreach(listAlbum)` through each `.row`. It will duplicate, I don't want this.

Have any idea to resolve my problem?

**Edit:** Full structure in `.col-md-4`:

```
<div class="news-post standard-post">
  <div class="post-gallery">
    <a href="Album_Detail.html"><img src="upload/news-posts/st1.jpg" alt=""> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <h2><a href="Album_Detail.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</a></h2>
    <ul class="post-tags">
      <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>27-Nov-2016</li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i><span>23</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to print 3xN table from `$listAlbum`?

Comment: do you just want to display the imageUrls and not the actual image ?

Comment: I updated my question in **Edit**. I want display struct like this.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov like this. I have to array `$listAlbum` and I want to print in N rows with each row contain 3 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a counter for the `$listAlbum` items. Increment the counter for each item and check if it is divisible by 3. If it is divisible by 3, re-open the row tag:

```
<?php
$listAlbum = [
  ['imgUrl' => 'url1'],
  ['imgUrl' => 'url2'],
  ['imgUrl' => 'url3'],
  ['imgUrl' => 'url4'],
  ['imgUrl' => 'url5'],
];

echo "<div class='container'>\n\t<div class='row'>\n";

$i = -1;
foreach ($listAlbum as $item) {
  if (++$i && $i % 3 == 0)
    echo "\t</div>\n\t<div class='row'>\n";
  echo "\t\t<div class='col-md-4'>", $item['imgUrl'], "</div>\n";
}

if (++$i % 3)
  echo str_repeat("\t\t<div class='col-md-4'></div>\n", 3 - $i % 3);

echo "\t</div>\n</div>";
```

*Sample Output*

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>url1</div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>url2</div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>url3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>url4</div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>url5</div>
        <div class='col-md-4'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add option only PHP nested in HTML? I write code in View `.phtml`, so I call like <?php ?> in `.phtml` insead of `.php`.

Comment: @vanloc, you can replace `<?php... echo "string";, ... ?>` with `<?php ... ?>string<?php...` as in  [this example](https://gist.github.com/88247d97d4b7746f2f69c35391ce8092). But I don't think it is a good idea, because it is difficult to read PHP mixed with HTML. You can prepare a 2D array of rows and cells in the controller for more convenient iteration in the view ([example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fda7cb9edfff1534db1eebe288d3939b)). Consider using a template engine such as Twig or Smarty

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php $col = 0; foreach($listAlbum as $item) {
        if($col && !($col%3)){echo '</div><div class="row">';}
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">$item['imgUrl']</div>
    <?php $col++; } ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Sample code:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<30;$i++){
$listAlbum[]= 'item '.$i;
}
 ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php $col = 0; foreach($listAlbum as $item) {
    if($col && !($col%3)){echo '</div><div class="row">';}
    ?>
       <div class="col-md-4"><?php echo $item ?></div>
     <?php $col++; } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have to array $listAlbum and I want to print in N rows with each row contain 3 items. Not limit three item in `.row` element.

Comment: It will work for an array with n number of items. Please check the sample code I have added.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is optional. I tested and it's also working like @Ruslan Osmanov. I have a question if I also want limit `.row`.

Comment: do you want to add multiple  .row in the same loop ?  @vanloc

Comment: yes. I want limit only 5 `.row`. Currently, it will load all items in database. If I have 30 items it will print 10 rows. I want limit only 5 rows.

Comment: You can limit the number of items loaded from database by adding 'LIMIT 15' to your query.

Comment: eg:- SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 15

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, I am not sure of the content of $item['imgUrl']

```
   <div class="container row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <?php foreach($listAlbum as $item) { ?>
                <div class="col-md-4"> <?php $item['imgUrl'] ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```